# How to get total streams of the song Spotify Web API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I am trying to get total stream of track from playlist TOP 50. I have tried to get Id of that track and the send another request, but it returns total streams only for my account.
How do I get total streams? Is it even possible?

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!accessToken) return alert("Failed OAUTH");
        axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF/tracks?fields=items(track(name%2C%20id)%2C%20track(album(images)%2C%20artists))', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        }).then(response => {
            const firstTrackId = response.data.items[0].track.id;
            setnameTopArtist(response.data.items[0].track.artists[0].name)
            axios.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/${firstTrackId}`, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                }
            }).then(res => {
                const firstTrackStreams = res.data.popularity;
                console.log("ress:" + res);
                console.log(`Počet poslechů první skladby: ${firstTrackStreams}`);
                setmonthlyListeners(firstTrackStreams);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }, [accessToken]);


    return (
        <div className="  max-w-5xl bg-primary ml-4 mr-4 mb-4 mt-4 rounded-lg md:ml-8 md:mr-8 md:mb-8 md:mt-8">
            {/*Left side*/}
            <div className= "mt-4 md:mt-8 gap-2 flex flex-col justify-left items-left" >

                {/* Verification icon*/}
                <div className=" ml-4  gap-1 flex flex-row justify-left items-center ">
                    <MdVerified className="w-6 h-6 md:w-12 h-12" />
                    <h2 className = "text-sm md:text-base ">Verified artist</h2>
                </div>

                {/*Artist name*/}

                <h2 className= "ml-4 md:ml-6 text-lg md:text-3xl font-bold">{nameTopArtist}</h2>

                {/*Monthly listeners*/}
                <h3 className= "text-sm md:text-base text-gray-300 ml-4 md:ml-6 ">{monthlyListeners} monthly listeners</h3>

            </div>


            {/*Right side with image*/ }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't possible with the Spotify Web API.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Spotify API does not provide a direct way to get the number of times a track has been played (or "streamed"). The closest approximation to this information would be the popularity score, which is a measure of the track's popularity on Spotify it's ranges from 0 to 100 integer value in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-track).

Comment: @BenchVue Oh... I am little bit dissapointed. I am already angry, because img of the artist is returned with ugly background.... I had tried it with popularity, but it returns so small number(for the first one and most streamed 830)...

Comment: The first song's (Miley Cyrus) Flowers's [popularity](https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4DHcnVTT87F0zZhRPYmZ3B) is 89 and image is should be [fine](https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27358039b5147731b6e52202e46). I think your code problem for background.

Comment: The problem I have with Image is backround. I would like to use image withouth background. I had to search for some useful API. I have found Remove.bg, but it is free only for first 50 requests

Answer (score 0):

Spotify *does* have an API for the number of streams for an artist's top tracks, just not a public one. You can find the JSON response to the graphQl query in the network tab of your browser's devtools easily enough. "Borrowing" it really isn't all that: https://apify.com/augeas/spotify-monthly-listeners